# How to substitute this.props.dispatch in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm separating my code by writing a function in another .js file.

The problem is that I don't have the access to my redux connect function since I'm not using a class in my new .js file.

To clear things up:

This is the function (*barChange*) inside my class which I want to move in another js file

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
   bar_change:store.bar_change
  };
})
export default class Bardoctor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);

   }
  barChange(arg0){
   //function code...
    this.props.dispatch(user.changeBarNum(arg0,"bar_change_doctor"));
    this.props.dispatch(user.sendBarDataDoctor("doctor_bar_send",temp_arr, flag_it, arg0));
  }
```

In order to use my user. functions I have to have the **this.props.dispatch**.
How would I use this.props.dispatch if I pack the *barChange* function in another .js file and export the function and call it in my class?

For example:

```
import * as user from "../actions/asyncCAll.js"
export function barChange(arg0, prop_arr, prop_next, string_change, string_send){
  //function code...
    dispatch(user.changeBarNum(arg0,string_change));
    dispatch(user.sendBarDataPatient(string_send, temp_arr, flag_it, arg0));
}
```

Comment: Pass the `dispatch` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `store` to your new js file and use [dispatch method](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) of the store directly.

```
import store from 'path/to/your/store/file'

function barChange(arg0) {
  //function code...
  store.dispatch(user.changeBarNum(arg0, "bar_change_doctor"));
  store.dispatch(
    user.sendBarDataDoctor("doctor_bar_send", temp_arr, flag_it, arg0)
  );
}
```

If you're not creating your store in a separate file using `createStore` method, I recommend you to do that as follows.

```
const store = createStore(reducers, //...);

export default store;
```

*Warning: This approach might have complications if you use it with server-side rendering.*

Comment: Just a warning: import the store as a singleton lead to problems if you are developing an isomorphic/universal app.

Comment: I hope I'm not xd